# Toolbars and Headers don't have transparent backgrounds

Tags: 3d-view, customization

[image: heres a photo from a youtuber (look at the top and left side)]
heres a screenshot of a youtuber's blender UI (look at the top and left side)

[image: and here's my photo]
and here's a screenshot from my UI

what can I do to make the toolbar on the left and the header transparent?

Comment: also if you can, how to get rid of the text in my photo that says User Perspective and stuff, i've never used it, and it looks cleaner without it

Comment: nevermind, the text part of the problem is under Viewport in User Preferences, but I didn't fix the opaque menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! You just have to enable "Region Overlap" under User Preferences>Interface>Themes